# jQuery wait for keyup after keydown

Tags: javascript, jquery, keydown, keyup

I'd like to trigger an event once after key down and a different event only after the down arrow key has been released, like so:

```
$('body').keydown(function (e)
{
    if(e.keyCode==40)
    {
        //do something
    }
    $('body').keyup(function (d)
    {
        if(d.keyCode==40)
        {
            //do something else
        }
    }
}
```

This code only functions partially. The keydown is triggered continuously as the down arrow key is held.

I have a setInterval whose refresh rate I'm altering when I hold the arrow key. Unforunately setTimeOut isn't an option in this situation.

So my code looks something like this:

```
        clearInterval(interval);
        refresh = 100;
        interval();
```

Comment: Partially? So what is the part that does not work for you?

Comment: You're currently binding a new event handler to the onkeyup event whenever a keydown event occurs. Also, can you please be a bit more specific on your problem?

Comment: What exactly do you need - there are already two different events (one for `keydown`, one for `keyup`)?

Comment: I understand this code isn't functioning, I'm just trying to communicate what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('body').keydown(function (e) {
    if(e.keyCode==40) {
        //do something
    }
    return false;
})
.keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode==40) {
        //do something else
    }
    return false;
});


$('body').on('keyup', function (e) {
    if(e.keyCode==40) {
        //do something
    }
    // after first keyup set to handle next keydown only once:
    $(this).one('keydown', function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode==40) {
            //do something else
        }
    });
});
```

If you need exactly **trigger** the event and **not handle** as it's in your example, then you need to use [`$.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) method.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. I want to perform keydown only once until keyup.

Comment: This doesn't work until the keyup event has occurred once. Still, +1.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to **trigger** the `keyup` event instead of handle it?

Comment: No, you had it right, but since the "keydown" is nested inside the "keyup", it only happens correctly after an initial "keyup". And my terminology is shaky at best, so apologies if I miscomunicated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do some action only once while the key remains pressed, simply keep track of that:

```
var arrowKeyDown = false;

$('body').keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 40 && !arrowKeyDown) {
        arrowKeyDown = true;
        // ...
    }
});

$('body').keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 40) {
        arrowKeyDown = false;
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/utfwQ/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').keydown(function (e)
{
    console.log('down');
}​).keyup(function(e){console.log('up')});​​​​
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to remove the keyup listener when you're done,
http://jsfiddle.net/CgmCT/

```
document.body.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 40){
        console.log('key 40 down');
        // key down code
        document.body.addEventListener('keyup', function listener(d){
            if(d.keyCode === 40){
                document.body.removeEventListener('keyup', listener, true);
                console.log('key 40 up');
                // key up code
            }
        }, true);
    }
}, true);​
```